# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - Apache Web Server with SiteMinder Webagent

Tags: apache, spring-boot, networking, connection, siteminder

We have an Application built in Angular backed by Spring Boot web services.
Both Angular based UI and Spring boot apps are behind Apache 2.4 Web server. Apache web server has SiteMinder Webagent configured for authentication.
There is a feature to download files. Files are made to buffer in 1 MB chunks. At times and only for some users, after few minutes the file download fails with an error in console/browser developer tools.

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does this also occurs when your angular application communicates directly with spring boot rather than through your reverse proxy (apache)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question just to complete the thread and if by any chance it will be useful to someone else.

There was no issue with the(Spring Boot) Web Services that buffers file downloaded nor with Angular.

The application was protected by SiteMinder web agent. It was identified that Apache kept restarting a process by itself due to a bug in the version of SiteMinder web agent configured in Apache 2.4 web server.

An error was noticed in Event viewer related to a dll file **MSVCP80.dll**.

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.33.0, time stamp: 0x5abb6dc6

Faulting module name: MSVCP80.dll, version: 8.0.50727.9268, time stamp: 0x573d27ee

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x000000000000934a

Faulting process id: 0x1a4c

Faulting application start time: 0x01d4bfd450532ef6

Faulting application path: D:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9268_none_88e0de612fadfb38\MSVCP80.dll

Report Id: abcd (*changed)

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

A dll **HTTPPLUGIN.DLL** used by SiteMinder seemed to have dependency on the DLL causing the issue (MSVCP80.dll)

We came up with 2 solutions after troubleshooting.

1. To use linux server to configure Apache Web server with Siteminder webagent
2. There was no active support for the version used and client was willing to migrate the authentication mechanism to Azure AD, it was done using Spring Security with Spring Boot.